# Mac Install android studio on external ssd

Tags: android-studio, installation, external, solid-state-drive, tooling

We have a mac with lowest available memory (125 GB). Would like to install/run Android Studio and projects on an external SSD. If possible, Please share steps/guide to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can drag and drop android studio installer to external SSD. After open setup wizard you should select your external ssd of path. And you can complete your setup.

Note: Your external SSD format should APFS ! You will be get some errors in ExFAT format !

Answer (score 0):

I am using VSCode on my mini-mac on an external drive. I installed VSCode first, then moved it to the external drive by dragging/dropping it without an issue.

The only problem I ran into is Flutter would not run properly on external drive. I had to install flutter on the actual mac.

A quick google for android external drive install:
https://ishouldgotosleep.com/daily-learn/install-android-studio-external-ssd-flutter/

Comment: On moving Android Studio from Applications to `external SSD`. Receiving error `Missing essential plugins: com.intellij.java, com.intellij.java.ide, org.jetbrains.android`.